# Single word for company's internal solution?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word can define an internal solution created within company in contrast to the "external" solutions? Something like "home-made", but more formal and reffering to a company.

Comment: so calls for "broken"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think [In-house](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/In-house) may fit the context:

> - Conducted within, coming from, or being within an organization or group: an in-house computer system; in-house counsel; an in-house newsletter.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/In-house

Answer (score 5):

I think that "proprietary" sounds even more professional than "in-house".

Comment: Downvoting because "proprietary" is not interchangeable with "in-house". To quote wikipedia, "Proprietary software [...] is computer software licensed under exclusive legal right of the copyright holder with the intent that the licensee is given the right to use the software only under certain conditions, and restricted from other uses, such as modification, sharing, studying, redistribution, or reverse engineering.".

Comment: @AlexM. One answer does not necessarily have to be interchangeable with another answer - that's why there are so many words in a language, because each is nuanced.  I think "proprietary" answers the OP's question very well, and is in fact the first word I thought of, too.

Comment: @AlexM. Additionally, while your quote may be correct regarding proprietary *software*, that is not the only context in which "proprietary" can be used.

Comment: Indeed, I did not notice software wasn't the only thing covered. Sorry. If you edit your answer to unlock it, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: The original question never mentions the word software.

Comment: The problem is that "proprietary" is ambiguous due to its other meanings, whereas "in-house" is not.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, "in-house solution" is common and has all the formal and professional meanings that "home-made" does not. "External solution", "commercial solution" or "3rd-party solution" would be the opposites. However, an in-house solution would also clearly say that it isn't immediately compatible with anything else out there.

If you end up numbering things do not, under any circumstances, use the phrase "final solution" - very bad meaning.

Comment: I shouldn't write that, but +1 for "final solution"